# Using MAX(), GROUP BY and INNER JOIN together

Tags: sql, ms-access

I can't quite see how to make this work but maybe I am just tired.

I want to see all the records from *survey* that have *survey.depth* greater than *collar.max_depth*. The linked fields are *hole_id* in both tables.

```
SELECT survey.hole_id, MAX(survey.depth)
FROM survey
INNER JOIN collar
ON survey.hole_id = collar.hole_id
GROUP BY survey.hole_id
HAVING (MAX(survey.depth)>collar.max_depth)
;
```

I have looked through articles on here but none of them are quite the same.

Comment: and what is wrong with your query?

Comment: add a full [mre] with data so that we can idestand what is wrong with your query

Comment: You haven't asked a question ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `survey==>collar` is an `N to 1` relationship, It seems like you just want:

```
SELECT survey.*
FROM survey
INNER JOIN collar
ON survey.hole_id = collar.hole_id
WHERE survey.depth > collar.max_depth
```

It's not clear why you need a `GROUP BY`.